Se dire vs dire
I'm trying to translate this sentence:
"On a tant de choses à se dire et à voir" which would be translated as "We have so many things to say and see".
But the real deal is the following: why do we need to use the reflexive verb here?

We don't need to use the reflexive form here but doing it slightly changes the meaning.
De choses à dire means 'we have many things to say' (to whomever listen).
De choses à se dire means 'we have many things to say to each other'.

Thank you so much!

The snag is with On, which may stand for "anyone" as well as for "we". In this particular sentence, it stands for "we".
Hence my proposed translation: "there's so much to exchange about and to see", not "there's so much to ponder about and to see".
